# How do I make new lines in pyautogui.prompt()?

Tags: python, pyautogui

This is my current code:

```
result = pyautogui.confirm(text = "message<NewLineSeparatorThingy>message2")
```

how do I do that?

Comment: Did you try with `\n`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `\n`

```
result = pyautogui.confirm(text="message\nmessage2")
```

If `message` and `message2` are variables, you can use f-string to format it.

```
result = pyautogui.confirm(text=f"{message}\n{message2}")
```

Comment: it kind of works but I can't send in variables "message" and "message2"

Comment: just do f"{message}\n{message2}"

Answer (score 1):

```
result = pyautogui.confirm(text = f"{message}\n{message2}")
```